# Xamarin Forms define application workflow with configuration (like json etc)

Tags: android, json, xamarin.forms, workflow

I am new to stack overflow. So sorry, if the question is already answered, but I didn't find a suitable answer.

Is it possible to define process steps using a config file like this in Xamarin Forms:

```
{
  "step" : "acceptOrder", 
  "nextStep" : "DestinationScan"
}
```

The goal is to configure which `views` (with appropriate `ViewModels`) should be used. So to predefine a workflow.

```
Open View1 
  wait for result
Open View2
 ...
```

Hope this is clear =)

Thank you for any advices!

Regards,
Dennis

I search the internet for some days, but could not find a suitable answer. Maybe I am note sure what I am searching for.

So I hope to get some hints here to clarify my goals =)

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible.  Your navigation logic can use a config file to determine which page to navigate to next in sequence.  However it's a pretty broad topic and really difficult to give a concise answer to.

Comment: Thank you for the advice =) Do you know some starting points to go deeper into the topic?

Comment: No, this is not a very common requirement so its unlikely you're going to find anything that specifically addresses it.

Comment: AFAIK, you would write C# code yourself to read the config file, and create the pages. Reading config file: not specific to xamarin, search for c# or .net custom config files. Creating pages: your main page will be either `xamarin NavigationPage` or `xamarin AppShell`. Search for those docs, to see how to programmatically navigate to a page.

Comment: How I would approach this: 1. Implement a wrapper over default navigation service in Xamarin to support programatically ViewModel navigation. (Or use a MVVM framework, but might be a bit harder to control the "wait for result part") 2. Create a Workflow reader that reads the JSON fine and interacts with your NavigationService. You can take this to next level and define workflows using Elsa (https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core).